# Send Data From PHP to C# or VB.NET

Tags: c#, php, vb.net

Today'm trying to pass a variable and an array of PHP to a desktop application, but I have no clue how to do it.

To be more precise in my question I need PHP run the Desktop Application Developed in C # or VB.NET and send a variable.

If anyone can help me with some solution,suggestion or method is welcome Thank You.

Comment: when you say desktop what OS are you using, Windows?  Are you looking for the PHP to run on the desktop or on a separate server?

Comment: The web server is Linux (Centos 5.6), I need PHP RUN the Desktop App in the Client (Microsoft XP)

Comment: The Developed APP is hosted in the Same Client PC. For Example: <?php run('C:/app.exe?var=this_is_an_example'); ?>

Comment: Here how to execute program http://php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php, add to execution path some parameters and handle this parameters in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send the information to the client in a format you can parse client side. XML would be one example.

So if you go the XML route (I'd look for a better transport data structure)

1. PHP outputs XML when the client application requests the data
2. The client then parses the XML pulling the data from it and storing it as a native data structure

Answer (score 1):

Given your clarification in your comment (that you want to do this on the client machine), the answer is you can't.  PHP doesn't run on the clients machine, it runs on your server and outputs to the clients browser, the browser then interprets that and displays the results, the browser doesn't run other applications as that is asecurity breach...except when downloading certain mime-types.  If you are doing this with the users knowing cooperation, that might be a solution.  If you control both code bases (the PHP and C#), then it's more likely, it would make more sense for the user to run the desktop app and for it to communicate with the PHP page to get the info it has.